C++ program does not display elements read from a matrix declared through a class
I declared a matrix through a double pointer. I need to check if the matrix is square or not and, if so, the program has to display the elements from the secondary diagonal and the elements from under the 1st diagonal.
#include <iostream>
#define dim 10
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
    int** m, col, lin;

public:
    int getElement(int l, int c) { return m[l][c]; }
    Matrix(int lin, int col)
    {
        m = new int*[lin];
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
            m[i] = new int[col];

        if (m == NULL)
        {
            cout << "\nEroare la alocarea memoriei necesare!";
            exit(1);
        }
        else cout << "\nMemorie alocata cu success\n";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                m[i][j] = 0;
    }
    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
            delete[] m[i];
        delete[] m;
    }

    void setElement(int l, int c, int v)
    {
        m[l][c] = v;
    }

    int getElement(int l, int c)
    {
        return m[l][c];
    }

    void print2ndDiag();
    void print_subDiag();
    void matrix01();
};

void readMatrix(Matrix& x, int lin, int col);
void displayMatrix(Matrix x, int lin, int col);

int main()
{
    int l, c;
    cout << "Introduceti dimensiunile matricii:\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\tNr linii: ";
        cin >> l;
        if (l<1 || l>dim)
            cout << "Dimensiune invalida! Incercati din nou...\n";
    } while (l<1 || l>dim);

    do 
    {
        cout << "\tNr coloane: ";
        cin >> c;
        if (c<1 || c>dim)
            cout << "Dimensiune invalida! Incercati din nou...\n";
    } while (c<1 || l>dim);
    
    Matrix x(l, c);
    cout << "Introduceti elementele:\n\n";
    readMatrix(x, l, c);
    displayMatrix(x, l, c);
    x.print2ndDiag();
    x.print_subDiag();
    x.matrix01();

    return 0;
}

void readMatrix(Matrix& x, int lin, int col)
{
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cin >> a;
            x.setElement(i, j, a);
        }
}

void displayMatrix(Matrix x, int lin, int col)
{
    cout << "\nElementele matricii sunt:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cout << x.getElement(i, j) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void Matrix::print2ndDiag()
{
    if (lin != col)
    {
        cout << "Matricea nu este patratica, deci nu se pot afisa elementele de pe diagonala secundara.\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "Elementele de pe diagonala secundara sunt:\n ";
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        cout << m[i][col - 1 - i] << " ";
    cout << "\n";

    //nu stiu de ce nu afiseaza nimic
}


void Matrix::print_subDiag()
{
    if (lin != col)
    {
        cout << "Matricea nu este patratica, deci nu se pot afisa elementele de sub diagonala principala\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "Elementele de sub diagonala principala sunt:\n";
    for (int i=1;i<lin;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col - 1; j++)
        {
            if (j < i)
                cout << m[i][j];
            else cout << " ";
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void Matrix::matrix01()
{
    int treshold, ct = 0;
    cout << "Introduceti valoarea de prag: ";
    cin >> treshold;

    cout << "Matricea rezultata este:\n";
    for (int i=0;i<lin;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] >= treshold)
            {
                cout << 1;
                ct++;
            }
            else cout << 0;
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Matricea ";
    if ((float)lin * col / ct < 0.67)
        cout << "nu este rara.\n\n";
    else cout << "este rara.\n\n";
}

The algorithm does not work. At first it did work, but it did not display the elements I requested + stack corruption, so something within the loop was wrong. I changed it and now it doesn't print anything. What can I do regarding this?
Thank you

Read about "the rule of three" and about how to pass function arguments as references.

Related to the above comment, you should not pass the Matrix by value here: void displayMatrix(Matrix x, int lin, int col)  If the copy is implemented correctly this becomes inefficient to do so and since your code violates the rule of 3 it will cause a double delete of m You should fix the rule of 3 and also pass the matrix by const reference here so it should be void displayMatrix(const Matrix & x, int lin, int col)

tactical note: The array of pointers to arrays is one of the least effective ways of implementing a matrix. The CPU often spends more time chasing pointers and handling cache misses than it does real work. Instead make one array and perform the indexing math yourself.

Does this answer your question? What is The Rule of Three?

I am currently studying classes in University, this is my first contact with classes and things like this and in all the documentation that I have, I can't find anything related to "the rule of three" and, unfortunately, I don't quite understand what I found on the internet. So if you would be willing to explain me like as simple as it can be explained, I would be very grateful. Thank you

Good link above, but the TL;DR version is if a class manages a resource like a dynamically allocated object, you need to make sure the resource is correctly copied along with the class. Default copy behaviour is to copy the pointer, not the object at the pointer. This usually leaves you with two objects Owning the same resource. If that doesn't kill the program quickly, it will when both owners try to free the same resource

Looks like you currently have 2 implementations of getElement: https://godbolt.org/z/9b64e579q

Fixing the above and turning on some extra diagnostics, and feeding in I get https://godbolt.org/z/Ka6f43xo5 demonstrating the double free.

I am sorry for the confusion. The displayMatrix function works, BUT the void print2ndDiag(), print_subDiag() and void matrix01() only print the message, but the numbers don't get printed. I don't know if I am supposed to use getElement by any mean. I am sorry for having such rookie mistakes and questions, but all I do it is self taught, teachers don't quite do their job regarding Computer Programming

Sadly they rarely do. For example, before you got to writing code like this , someone should have covered the Rule of Three. You can't write effective and efficient C++ without a good understanding of the rules of three, five, and zero. Supplement your education with one of the introductory texts from here.

void displayMatrix(Matrix x, int lin, int col); passes the matrix by value, there's the accidental copy. Fixing that, void displayMatrix(Matrix& x, int lin, int col);, there is a memory leak and a logic error elsewhere that's  breaking the data being printed: https://godbolt.org/z/dz3f45M77

The displayMatrix function works Calling the displayMatrix() currently with the the rule of 3 violation of the Matrix class causes UB and any results after calling this function are no longer valid.

OT / not related to the problem:  void displayMatrix(Matrix x, int lin, int col) do you really need the lin and col parameters to this function? Doesn't the Matrix class already know its dimensions?

Has anyone shown you debuggers yet? If not, spend a few hours practicing with one. This code will be a wonderful introduction to stepping through code and setting breakpoints. The rest is observation. A debugger can't show you the bugs, the debugger doesn't know what the program SHOULD do, it can't, but it can show you what the program does. It's on you to watch what it does and spot where the does deviates from the should.

Here's a quick walk-though of Visual Studio's debugger. If you're not using Visual Studio, it doesn't matter too much. Decades of evolution has resulted in all debuggers working pretty much the same and the only major differences being what the icons look like and where the buttons are.

Basic use is set a breakpoint a bit before where you think the problem is (right at the top of main if you have no clue) and start stepping. As soon as you see the program do something you didn't expect, you've spotted a bug. The earlier you catch the  discrepancy, the closer you are to the bug. If you're really observant, you'll spot it immediately, otherwise you'll spot some side-effect of the bug and have to work backward, running the program again and a gain until you see the cause.

FYI, pointers can (and often do) point to anywhere.  References refer to an existing object.  Pointers don't indicate the size of what they point to.
